# Every time I try to log in or press login, I am stuck at the run method

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying login through my login page. Each time I enter a value in the fields or just press login I notice that on my browser it stops at the run method and my page is left blank.

My database has two columns with the actual title "Username" and "Password".
I can't seem to figure out what is causing this.

Here is my login_model.php file:

```
<?php

class Login_Model extends BaseModel {

  public function __contruct(){
    parent:: __construct();
  }

  public function run() {

    $sth = $this->database->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE
      Username = :username AND Password = :password");
      $sth->execute(array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':password' => $_POST['password']
      ));

      //$data = $sth->fetchAll();
      $count =  $sth->rowCount();
      if ($count > 0){
        //login
        Session::init();
        Session::set('loggedIn', true);
        header('location: ../controllers/dashboard');
      } else {
        //show error
        header('location: ../login/loginIndex');
      }
  }
}


?>
```

This is what I have within my login.php file from the controller:

```
<?php

class Login extends BaseController {

  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }
  //this is to avoid interference with the page that I want to call
  function index() {
    $this->view->render('../views/login/loginIndex');
  }

  function run(){
  $this->model->run();
  }

  // public function other() {
  //   require '../models/loginModel.php';
  //   $model = new loginModel();
  // }

}
```

This is the place I am trying to end up at:

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends BaseController {

  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    Session::init();
    // You set the variable session: LoggedIn if they pass the condition
    $logged = Session::get('loggedIn');
    if ($logged == false){
      Session::destroy();
      header('location: ../login/loginIndex');
      exit;
    }
  }
  //this is to avoid interference with the page that I want to call
  function index() {
    $this->view->render('../views/dashboard/adminPage');
  }
}
```

Update:

So after adding the following code you mentioned, this is what I got:

> Notice: Undefined property: Login::$model in /apps/help-i-need-a-tutor/controllers/login.php on line 19
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function run() on a non-object in /apps/help-i-need-a-tutor/controllers/login.php on line 19

How do I go about finding out the cause of my issue here? I've had a look at the run method in my login_model.php class and cannot seem to find where this error may be coming from.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that you don't have an instance of `Login_Model` within `Login`.

Try inserting `private $model` above your constructor within `Login`, and then assigning to it within your constructor with `$model = new Login_Model()`

Comment: So i have tried your method by placing private $model above function __construct() and then placed inside that constructor $model = new Login_Model();. I received the following error... Fatal error: Class 'Login_Model' not found in /apps/help-i-need-a-tutor/controllers/login.php on line 13. So then I added require '../models/login_model.php'; which I then got another kind of error stating Fatal error: Call to a member function run() on a non-object in /apps/help-i-need-a-tutor/controllers/login.php on line 24.